# Group by issue using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to perform aggregation on a table. But it is not aggregating properly for some cases. Please find the below input.

Table t1.

```
CHANNEL;VALUE;STATUS;ERROR_CODE;RND_TIMESTAMP;SESSION_CD;NAR;
-------------------------------------------------------------    
USD;4;12;;2-NOV-2015 11:00:00;;
USD;4;12;;2-NOV-2015 11:00:00;;
USD;2;12;;2-NOV-2015 11:00:00;;
USD;3;12;;2-NOV-2015 11:00:00;;
```

Output table t2

```
CHANNEL;VALUE;STATUS;ERROR_CODE;HOUR_TIMESTAMP;SESSION_CD;NAR;
--------------------------------------------------------------    
USD;5;12;;2-NOV-2015 11:00:00;;
```

Query:

```
select 
    channel, sum(value), 
    status, error_code, rnd_timestamp, session_cd, nar
from 
    t1
where 
    rnd_timestamp > (select max(hour_timestamp) from t2)
group by 
    channel, status, error_code, rnd_timestamp, session_cd, nar
```

Why is it not considering the other 2 rows for aggregation. Is it because some columns in group by have null? How to solve this issue?

Output must be :

```
USD;13;12;;2-NOV-2015 11:00:00;;
```

Comment: This is most likely because some data in the fields that are all shown as blank above is not the same for all rows.  It could be an empty string in one row and NULL in another row, for example.

Comment: The only filter is on rnd_timestamp. Maybe some rows have another timezone? Try a to_char with full specs.

Comment: all rows have same timezone.

Comment: Take the `WHERE` out and retest. According to your description it should be fine. Also actually list the rows (without the `GROUP BY`) and see what they look like. Two basic problem solving exercises you could undertake.

Comment: One other thing - 2-NOV-2015 11:00:00 is not greater than 2-NOV-2015 11:00:00, so your `rnd_timestamp > (select max(hour_timestamp) from t2)` would return no rows given the above sample data in t1 and t2.

Comment: @Boniest : It considers its last entry. viz 2-NOV-2015 10:00:00   . I need to handle empty string and null which are different in group by . Any help here?

Comment: You should make sure your sample input and output data matches, and also explains your situation accurately. Currently, your query would return no rows with the above data you've provided for t1 and t2 (the t1.rnd_timestamp values are the same as the max(t2.hour_timestamp) value, which fails the greater-than check.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think your query has an issue?

By switching the hour_timestamp in t2 to be 10am not 11am, your query works as expected for me:

```
with t1 as (select 'USD' channel, 4 value, 12 status, null error_code, to_date('02/11/2015 11:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') rnd_timestamp, null session_cd, null nar from dual union all
            select 'USD' channel, 4 value, 12 status, null error_code, to_date('02/11/2015 11:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') rnd_timestamp, null session_cd, null nar from dual union all
            select 'USD' channel, 2 value, 12 status, null error_code, to_date('02/11/2015 11:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') rnd_timestamp, null session_cd, null nar from dual union all
            select 'USD' channel, 3 value, 12 status, null error_code, to_date('02/11/2015 11:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') rnd_timestamp, null session_cd, null nar from dual),
     t2 as (select 'USD' channel, 5 value, 12 status, null error_code, to_date('02/11/2015 10:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') hour_timestamp, null session_cd, null nar from dual)
--- end of mimicking your tables t1 and t2 with data in; see SQL below:
select   channel,
         sum(value), 
         status,
         error_code,
         rnd_timestamp,
         session_cd,
         nar
from     t1
where    rnd_timestamp > (select max(hour_timestamp) from t2)
group by channel,
         status,
         error_code,
         rnd_timestamp,
         session_cd,
         nar;

CHANNEL SUM(VALUE)     STATUS ERROR_CODE RND_TIMESTAMP         SESSION_CD NAR
------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------- ---------- ---
USD             13         12            02/11/2015 11:00:00
```